# ANDROID ANDENGINE -- Set Scene background as trasparent

Tags: android, background, transparent, andengine, scene

­I'm starting to use AndEngine in my app.
I've used an xml to define the base style of the app.
I've defined a scene in which I'll have some draggable sprites.

I've imported correctly the xml but the scene appears on top of that with a black background that hides the xml graphics. I need to set the scene with transparent background.

How can i do that?

Comment: can you submit some of the xml file?

Comment: Can you please share solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can do that.

It was at least working some time ago with AndEngine running on top of a Camera preview.

It has really been a while since I did this and I didn't keep it up to date, but this class should be of interest for you:
http://code.google.com/p/andengineaugmentedrealityextension/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/extension/augmentedreality/BaseAugmentedRealityGameActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

The default background of the scene is black. you can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

It can change . Use this code.

```
 @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
            this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

            final Scene scene = new Scene();
            scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer has been added when the question was solved over 2 years ago.