# Andengine transparent scene background in SimpleLayoutGameActivity

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I'm facing with an app which needs some physics and I decided to use Andengine with box2d extension.

Starting from Andengine examples and some (a lot of) googling I ended up with the structure I was needing: a standard android layout containing a RenderSurfaceView where the physic stuff happens.

BTW I now have a problem that after a lot of attempts I can't solve:
this is my screen

[image]

The black box is where physics stuff happens and evertything works as expected, but I need it to have a transparent background. I tried a lot of things but no way.

This is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/main_gradient_background">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/main2_dataContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border_top_white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">

            <com.squadrone.android.ui.SuperLabel
                android:id="@+id/btn_get_involved"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="12,29502 BTC =  4862,51 EUR"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <com.squadrone.android.ui.SuperButton
                android:id="@+id/btnContinueSell"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#0099FF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="TEST"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main2_physicContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_above="@+id/main2_dataContainer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">



        <org.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/xmllayoutexample_rendersurfaceview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0px"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:alpha="1"/>

        <com.squadrone.android.ui.SuperLabel
            android:id="@+id/btn_get_involved"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="12€"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my Activity

```
public class MyPhysicsActivity extends SimpleLayoutGameActivity implements IAccelerationListener, IOnSceneTouchListener {

    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    protected static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = ConioApplication.getScreenWidth();
    protected static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = ConioApplication.getScreenHeight();

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================
    protected ITiledTextureRegion mCircleFaceTextureRegion;
    protected PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
    private Scene mScene;
    private int mFaceCount = 0;


    @Override
    protected int getLayoutID() {
        return R.layout.xmllayoutexample;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getRenderSurfaceViewID() {
        return R.id.xmllayoutexample_rendersurfaceview;
    }

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Touch the screen to add objects.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, MyPhysicsActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH, MyPhysicsActivity.CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new
                FixedResolutionPolicy(MyPhysicsActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH, MyPhysicsActivity.CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 64, 64, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
        this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "face_circle_tiled.png", 0, 0, 1, 1); // 64x32
        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetContentView() {
        super.onSetContentView();
    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        Debug.d("oncreate scene");
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        this.mScene = new Scene();
        this.mScene.setBackground(new Background(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        this.mScene.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);

        this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);

        final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
        int h = findViewById(R.id.main2_dataContainer).getMeasuredHeight();
        int marginBottom = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.main2_dataContainer).getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin;
        int baseX = h + marginBottom;

        int martingLeft = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.main2_physicContainer).getLayoutParams()).leftMargin;
        int martingRight = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.main2_physicContainer).getLayoutParams()).rightMargin;

        int physicsW = (CAMERA_WIDTH) - martingLeft - martingRight;
        int physicsH = (CAMERA_HEIGHT) - marginBottom - h;


        final Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(0 + (physicsW / 2), baseX + 0, physicsW, 0, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle roof = new Rectangle(0 + (physicsW / 2), (CAMERA_HEIGHT - 0), physicsW, 0, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0,baseX+physicsH/2, 0, physicsH, vertexBufferObjectManager);

        final Rectangle right = new Rectangle(physicsW-0, baseX+physicsH/2, 0, physicsH, vertexBufferObjectManager);

//        right.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
//        ground.setColor(Color.RED);
//        roof.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
//        left.setColor(Color.GREEN);
//        right.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, roof, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

        this.mScene.attachChild(ground);
        this.mScene.attachChild(roof);
        this.mScene.attachChild(left);
        this.mScene.attachChild(right);

        this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);

        return this.mScene;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        if (this.mPhysicsWorld != null) {
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                this.addItem(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerationAccuracyChanged(final AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerationChanged(final AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        final Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerationData.getX(), pAccelerationData.getY());
        this.mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);
        Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeGame() {
        super.onResumeGame();

        this.enableAccelerationSensor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseGame() {
        super.onPauseGame();

        this.disableAccelerationSensor();
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================

    private void addItem(final float pX, final float pY) {
        Debug.d("add item");
        this.mFaceCount++;
        Debug.d("items: " + this.mFaceCount);

        final Sprite face;
        final Body body;

        final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0f);

        face = new Sprite(pX, pY, this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        face.setScale(MathUtils.random(0.5f, 1.25f));
        body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);

        this.mScene.attachChild(face);
        this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true));
    }

}
```

I tried with this links with no luck

[AndEngine Applying Transparancy to AndEngine View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862505/andengine-applying-transparancy-to-andengine-view)

[ANDROID ANDENGINE -- Set Scene background as trasparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905792/android-andengine-set-scene-background-as-trasparent)

Is it possible to do what I need?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I changed AndEngine to use as View and had the same problem with transparency.

[Here](https://gitlab.com/okryvoshta/Transparent-AndEngine-View) you can find simple example how I solved it.

Loot at the screen shot: here is #880000 background and AndEngine view with #22000000 background and 20dp marging.

[image]